# SQL convert from multiple colums to few columns?

Tags: mysql, unpivot

in sql table

i have 100 company names in 1st column.
in next 20 columns there are 20 months like Jul 2011,....Jul 2012... (these month columns contain numeric demand data for every company)

I want to have only 3 columns : company name, month, demand.
(each company name will be repeated 20 times)

how can i convert this using sql code??

Comment: you want to convert column to row

Comment: Sounds like an unpivot operation. I added the tag - follow it to find similar questions

Comment: MS SQL server 2008.
Am trying to do that using 'cursor'.
I am not sure if there is any easier way?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to normalize your database. You should create at least 2 tables:

```
company: 
- id
- name

value:
- company_id
- value
- month (numeric)
```

And then you could relate each value (in the "values" table) with the corresponding company and the corresponding month.

Answer (score 0):

Use the unpivot command. This examples takes a single row and converts it into two rows.

The following example takes two rows and converts it to four.

```
    WITH xset
         AS (SELECT 'Expedition' ford
                  , 'Corvette' gm
                  , DATE '2013-01-01' ford_raise
                  , DATE '2013-09-03' gm_raise
                  , 1 seq
               FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Fusion'
                  , 'Escalate'
                  , DATE '2010-07-04'
                  , DATE '2001-12-31'
                  , 2
               FROM DUAL)
    SELECT *
      FROM xset UNPIVOT ((event_date, model) FOR event IN ((ford_raise, ford) AS 'Ford Raise', (gm_raise, gm) AS 'GM Raise'))
```

Comment: It's MySQL...as I know, there is no UNPIVOT function in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no `UNPIVOT` function in MySQL, so you need to do this with `UNION ALL` :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b614/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(5), `m1` int, `m2` int, `m3` int, `m4` int, `m5` int, `m6` int, `m7` int, `m8` int, `m9` int, `m10` int, `m11` int, `m12` int, `m13` int, `m14` int, `m15` int, `m16` int, `m17` int, `m18` int, `m19` int, `m20` int)
;

INSERT INTO MyTable
    (`id`, `name`, `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4`, `m5`, `m6`, `m7`, `m8`, `m9`, `m10`, `m11`, `m12`, `m13`, `m14`, `m15`, `m16`, `m17`, `m18`, `m19`, `m20`)
VALUES
    (1, 'name1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
    (2, 'name2', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
    (3, 'name3', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
;

CREATE TABLE Company
    ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name CHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (id))
;

CREATE TABLE Demand
    (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `company_id` int,  `month` varchar(3), `value` varchar(5), PRIMARY KEY (id))
;

INSERT INTO Company 
SELECT id,name FROM Mytable;

INSERT INTO Demand (company_id, month, value) 
SELECT id,'m1' as month, m1 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m2' as month, m2 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m3' as month, m3 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m4' as month, m4 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m5' as month, m5 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m6' as month, m6 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m7' as month, m7 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m8' as month, m8 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m9' as month, m9 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m10' as month, m10 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m11' as month, m11 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m12' as month, m12 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m13' as month, m13 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m14' as month, m14 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m15' as month, m15 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m16' as month, m16 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m17' as month, m17 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m18' as month, m18 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m19' as month, m19 as value FROM Mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,'m20' as month, m20 as value FROM Mytable
```